# NameError: name 'years' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

New to python programming, when executing i get:
print_target_output(principal,rate,years)
NameError: name 'years' is not defined

What i want to do is to calculate years and print it

Any idea how do i fix this?

```
def calculate_years_to_target(principal, rate, target):   
  years = math.log(target/principal) / 4*(math.log(1 + rate/4))
  return years

def print_target_output(principal, rate, years):
  print(principal,rate,years)
  
 #MAIN
def main():  
 print_intro()
 principal,rate,target=get_target_input()
 calculate_years_to_target(principal,rate,target)
 print_target_output(principal,rate,years)
```

Comment: You did not define `years` variable, that's what the error message is saying. I think you wanted it to be equal to the result of your `calculate_years_to_target` function. Therefore, you should change the third line of main `calculate_years_to_target(principal,rate,target)` to use it's result to define years varibale, like: `years = calculate_years_to_target(principal,rate,target)`.

Comment: `print_target_ouput` seems to be unneccessary and it prints whatever the input is given. Instead you can do all the work in `calculate_years_to_target` itself. And, there are some undefined functions in `main()`. It is good to post the which works for users to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign your returned result to a variable when you call the function. If you do not do so, it will not be stored outside the scope of your function.

```
def main():  
 print_intro()
 principal,rate,target=get_target_input()

 ## Assign the returned result to a variable ##
 years = calculate_years_to_target(principal,rate,target)
 print_target_output(principal,rate,years)
```

To further your learning it may be of benefit to spend some time better understanding scopes and when you can/cannot access variables you assign in your code.

[RealPython](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/)

Answer (score 0):

In the `main` function, `year` isn't assigned a value.
Update the below line.

```
years = calculate_years_to_target(principal,rate,target)
```